# How to use both citations with brackets and et al.?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using IEEEtr bibliography style, so references appear inside brackets, like this: [1]. Occasionally, I'd like to use the name of the author, Cheng et al for example. Is there a way to do both automatically (I mean, without having to put the name of the authors by hand)?

Comment: Dou youse `biblatex-ieee` style?

Comment: @Bernard yes, I just want to occasionally mention the name of the authors. I was wondering if there was a way of doing this without messing my references and without doing it by hand.

Comment: With `biblatex` you have the `\citeauthor` command. Set `maxcitenames=` and `mincitenames=` as you wish. See §3.8.5 of the documentation of `biblatex`, from p. 97.

Comment: Oh! yes. Sorry for the slip.

Comment: @Bernard I tried \citeauthor but it's not working, it gives "undefined control sequence". Am I supposed to use other package?

Comment: You're supposed to use biblatex for that. Specify `[style=ieee]` .